# Incomplete Delayed Chained Payment Fees Payer

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

I'm setting up a delayed chained payment in PHP

I'm setting the feesPayer to `SECONDARYONLY`

```
$payRequest->feesPayer = 'SECONDARYONLY';
```

the transaction is made to the primary receiver

but the second leg of the chained payment (from primary to secondary receiver) is still pending.

then 90 days passed (payKey expired) and I did not complete the payment.

who pays the fees when the payKey expires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my messages with PayPal's support, I tell you that no one will pay the fees because the payment will be reverted back to the buyer ! 
So if you didn't complete the payment, it will go back and you will not be able to change the receivers during 90 days.